# ¿Cómo no ordenar de forma predeterminada?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-plugins

Estoy usando una consulta SQL para mostrar datos ordenados de manera DESC en una tabla con Datatables para ordenar de manera manual.

Lo que quiero es que al entrar el usuario lo vea ordenado como lo muestro en la consulta, no como lo ordena dataTables.

He probado este código en el  y no funciona. En pocas palabras es deshabilitar la ordenación predeterminada, pero que el usuario pueda ordenar pulsando luego en las cabeceras.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#dataTable').dataTable( {
    "bSort": false
  } );
} );
</script>
```

**Actualización:**
El problema es que tengo en el pie este código para traducir Datatables y al colocar el nuevo de esta manera me lanza un error en alert.

```
    <script>

  $('#dataTable').dataTable({
    "bSort": true, // Con esto le estás diciendo que se pueda ordenar, ponlo a 'true'
    "order": [] // Aquí le dices que el criterio de ordenación primero esté vació , o lo que es lo mismo, ninguno
  });

var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
language: {
    "decimal": "",
    "emptyTable": "No hay información",
    "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ resultados",
    "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 resultados",
    "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
    "infoPostFix": "",
    "thousands": ",",
    "lengthMenu": "Ver _MENU_ resultados",
    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "processing": "Procesando...",
    "search": "Buscar ideas/retos:",
    "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
    "paginate": {
        "first": "Primero",
        "last": "Ultimo",
        "next": "Siguiente",
        "previous": "Anterior"
    }
},


});
        </script>
```

Comment: Tienes una opción para deshabilitar el orden inicial: https://datatables.net/reference/option/order El primer ejemplo debería valerte

Comment: Hola @Jok!! Ya te he puesto la solución, cualquier duda me dices. Espero que sea de ayuda!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo tienes todo casi perfecto. Únicamente añade las líneas que te comento:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#dataTable').dataTable( {
    "bSort": true, // Con esto le estás diciendo que se pueda ordenar, ponlo a 'true'
    "order": [] // Aquí le dices que el criterio de ordenación primero esté vació , o lo que es lo mismo, ninguno
  } );
} );
</script>
```

En definitiva, pon el atributo `"bSort"` a `true`, y añade otro nuevo atributo que diga `"order": []` el cual indique que el criterio de ordenación por defecto, nada más crear la tabla sea vacío.

**Actualizado 1:** Prueba a poner estas etiquetas `<script></script>` al final de la página HTML, quizás sea por eso. Sino comprueba que tu tabla tiene el mismo ID, `dataTable`, al que haces referencia con JQuery.

**Actualizado 2:** Prueba a poner todo junto en el mismo de la siguiente manera, en vez de las dos cosas por separado. Vamos, de manera que te quede, tal que así:

```
<script>

var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
"bSort": true, // Con esto le estás diciendo que se pueda ordenar, ponlo a 'true'
"order": [], // Aquí le dices que el criterio de ordenación primero esté vació , o lo que es lo mismo, ninguno
language: {
    "decimal": "",
    "emptyTable": "No hay información",
    "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ resultados",
    "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 resultados",
    "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
    "infoPostFix": "",
    "thousands": ",",
    "lengthMenu": "Ver _MENU_ resultados",
    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "processing": "Procesando...",
    "search": "Buscar ideas/retos:",
    "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
    "paginate": {
        "first": "Primero",
        "last": "Ultimo",
        "next": "Siguiente",
        "previous": "Anterior"
    }
},


});
</script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! pero no me hace nada... no sé la razón. No sé si es porque coloco mal el script o qué... o la versión de datatables.

Comment: @Jok he actualizado la respuesta a ver si eso te ayuda. ¿Donde has puesto la etiqueta `<script></script>`? ¿Al principio o al final de la página? Prueba a ponerlo al final a ver. Si no lo has puesto, claro. Es que lo que te he mandado, lo he probado, y me funciona. Por eso, tiene que ser problema del script o el id de la DataTable que no coincide. Si ves que no, prueba a poner todo el código actualizando la pregunta e igual viendo más te puedo ayudar a ver ;D

Comment: He actualizado con lo que me pasa

Comment: Hola @Jok!! Te he puesto lo que puedes hacer para solucionarlo, en la **Actualización 2** de la respuesta está descrito lo que puedes intentar. Si te sigue dando error, publícame el tipo de error que te da exactamente y así puedo mirar mejor, cual es el problema, profa. ;D

Comment: Perfecto! ha funcionado sin error perfectamente. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Que bien!! Me alegro mucho!!